# Given a dll/exe (with or without .pdb), can I see what .obj files contribute to its size and how much?

Tags: c++, windows

I compiled a dll file with a whole bunch of cpp files. I want to see how much each cpp contributes to the final size of the dll, in order to cut down its size (say by excluding some libraries). Is there any way to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This ranges from quite difficult (which object do you charge library functions against) to impossible (when whole program optimization is used to inline across compilation unit boundaries).

I also suggest that it's not very useful.  You need to know which functions to target for slimming down, not just which files.

Generating a map file during the build (pass `/MAP` to `LINK.EXE`) is probably the best you can do.  [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx) also mentions something about symbol groups, which you might be able to use to your advantage as well.

Comment: Thanks, Ben.

Let me try to clarify my problem a bit first. I am trying to make a dll that exports lots of functions based on many libraries. The plan is not to slim down functions, but to exclude some not-that-important modules so that the resulting dll will be smaller. So it is helpful to know how much each module contributes to the size of the final dll. My impression is that as along as symbol from an .obj file is used, the entire .obj will be added to the final dll. 

So, even if the dll is built in debug mode and the .pdb file is available, it is pretty difficult to achieve this purpose?